# Client authentication in identity server

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, identity, duende-identity-server

I'm developing an authentication system in which i can create clients the client is an application with possible types (m2m native regular web app or single page application)
in the m2m application i want to define the authentication method (client credential basic, client credential post, JWT key)
so, I don't understand the difference between client credential basic and post is there extra configuration i need to do in the identity server to set the authentication method as client credential post or the difference between the 2 methods persist in the client part.

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0  Windows credentials was popular with c# but is worked only on Windows.  Most application are moving towards OAUTH 2 which is supported on Windows, Linux, and Mac.  It is a token based authentication.  Read this paragraph carefully : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#remoteauthenticationhandlertoptions-vs-authenticationhandlertoptions